# A way to do this: $this.text('&#94;');

Tags: jquery

I want to change change the symbol of a button from a ^ sign to one that is pointed to the opposite direction(don't know what it's called).

I want to do this throughout the .text() function that jQuery provides. Sample:

```
$this.text('&#94;');
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is not totally clear what is your question, do you need the arrows or the jQuery function?

Comment: Use `html` method instead of the `text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead:

```
$this.html('&#94;');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HZcwS/

Comment: Works! Demo is a bit superfluous

Answer (score 1):

The character you want is called [Unicode MODIFIER LETTER DOWN ARROWHEAD (U+02C5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c5/index.htm). You can achieve this with either the HTML entity or the literal Unicode character:

```
$("#html").html("&#709;")
$("#unicode").text("\u02c5")​
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bclennox/bsVW9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's an HTML entity, not text.
If you want to set the text directly, you should pass it the actual character.

Answer (score 0):

Use the escape code for a character instead of an HTML entity.

This is the code for the down arrow:

```
$('div').text('\u02C5');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Vdd2c/

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.